# Function call or definition inside object scope?

Tags: javascript

While going through VueJS sources I've come across [this piece](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/master/test/unit/features/options/inject.spec.js):

```
  const injectedComp = {
    inject: ['foo', 'bar'],
    render () {},
    created () {
      injected = [this.foo, this.bar]
    }
  }
```

My question is - what are `render ()` and `created ()` - function calls? definitions? something else? What exactly is happening in there?

Comment: They are functions held on an object - to call e.g. `injectedComp.render()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `render` and `created` are properties of the `injectedComp` object with function values. The syntax is for [method shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) is fairly new, introduced by the ES2015 specification. You can think of your example like this:

```
const injectedComp = {
  inject: ['foo', 'bar'],
  render: function render() {},
  created: function created() {
    injected = [this.foo, this.bar]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`render ()` and `created ()` are method definitions.

They are almost a shorthand for named functions:

```
const injectedComp = {
  inject: ['foo', 'bar'],
  render : function render() {},
  created: function created () {
    injected = [this.foo, this.bar]
  }
}
```

Method definitions are nearly identical to functions, except that they are not constructable.

So you could not write `new injectedComp.render()` for your example.